# Better microphone noise suppression in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, noise, noise-cancelling

Having acquired a new and supposedly good microphone (ModMic), I noticed that I'm still hearing a lot of noise in the recording - about as bad as with my old cheap microphone. I now think the reason is the quality of the sound card (it's the on-board sound card on Asus Z170 PRO GAMING motherboard). For the record, I hear very similar results from both microphone ports (front and rear). My microphone boost setting is at zero and the gain is at 100%, but I also tried different settings with similar results.

I tried to use two noise suppression tools:

1. The "Noise suppression" checkbox in Microphone Properties -> VoizReal Exp tab. This helps, but some background noise remains and it seems the voice is clipped.
2. The "Noise suppression" filter in OBS Studio. This works much better. No noise remains, and the voice quality is comparatively good.

The question is is it possible to apply a filter like (2) system-wide and not just in OBS Studio.